# Pointer initialization

Tags: c++, pointers

Sorry if this question has been asked before. On my search through SO I didn't find one that asked what I wanted to know.

Basically, when I have this:

```
typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    node *node;
} *head;
```

and do `node *newItem = new node;`

I am under the impression that I am declaring and reserving space, but not defining, a pointer to `struct node`, is that correct?

So when I do

`newItem->data = 100` and `newItem->next = 0`

I get confused. `newItem = 0`would declare what exactly? Both `data` and `next`? The object as a whole?

I'm especially confused when I use typedef. Which part is the macro? I assume node because that's how I call it, but why do I need it?

Finally, what happens when I do:

```
node *temp;
temp = new node;

temp = head->next;
head->next = newItem;
newItem->next = temp;
```

I mean, head->next is  a pointer pointing to object newItem, so I assume not to newItem.data or next themselves. So how can I use an uninitialized pointer that I described above safely like here? is head now not pointing to an uninitialized pointer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I am under the impression that I am
>   declaring and reserving space, but not
>   defining, a pointer to struct node, is
>   that correct?

No. You are declaring a pointer, allocating space on the stack for the pointer, and dynamically allocating storage for  a node to it it.

Don't confuse yourself by writing stuff like this:

```
typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    node * next;
} *head;
```

The way to write the struct in C++ is:

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    node * next;
};
```

You can now create a pointer:

```
node * pnode;
```

which allocates storage for the pointer.

and you can dynamically allocate storage for a node, and make the pointer point to it:

```
pnode =  new node;
```

or do it all in one:

```
node * pnode = new node;
```

Now when you say:

```
pnode->data = 10;
```

you are not allocating anything. You are *assigning* 10 to the member called `data` of the node instance pointed to by `pnode`. Of course, if you had given your node a constructor (which you should normally do), you could do it all in one:

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    node * next;

    node( int n, node * np ) : data( n ), next( np ) {}
};

node * pnode = new node( 10, 0 );
```

Answer (score 3):

```
node *newItem = new node;
```

You create:

- a new node on the heap (which in your case contains uninitialized values because you omitted the ()
- a pointer on the stack, which points to this new node.

  newItem->data = 100

simply sets the `data` member of the newly allocated node to 100.

Answer (score 3):

When you define your struct as you did and call `new` like you did, what you're doing is:

1. allocate a new `struct node` on the heap.
2. allocate space on the stack for `newItem` and set its value to the address of the new struct you allocated.

You didn't set any values to *any* of the members of the new struct.  If you want that to happen whenever you create a new instance of the struct, you need to define a constructor.

Answer (score 3):

```
typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    node *node;
} *head;
```

This declares `node` as a struct and defines `head` as a synonym for `node*`, so `head` is a type and not an object.

This makes this illegal: `temp = head->next;` because `->` is not something that you can apply to a type.

`new node` dynamically allocates a `node` object and returns a pointer to it. `node *newItem = new node;` assigns this pointer to `newItem`. Note, though, that `newItem->node` (`node` here is a pointer object and not the type `node`) is not initialized so is neither null nor points to a valid `node` object.

This is also illegal because `node` has no `next` member.

```
newItem->next = temp;
```

I suggest that you choose a naming convention that means that you keep your types and your variables separate. It is somewhat confusing.